# The minimum number of rows that sum to a given number in Python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a DataFrame with cash, inflows and outflows.
I need to create a feature `survival` that is the maximum number of periods the cash is enough to pay the projection of outflows (excluding the inflows from the computation).

Let's take an example from the table below.

(*Again, the inflows do not count in this exercise*). 
In `t=1`, from the starting cash = 100, I can add the outflows: -20, -50, -10, -10 e still having a positive cash (100-20-50-10-10 = 10 > 0) while with the outflow in t=5 the cash would be negative. So, as long as I can "survive" 4 periods in t=1 the `survival = 4`.
In `t=2` the `survival = 3` and so on.

As it is a big DataFrame, how can I do it efficiently with Pandas?

| t | cash | outflow | inflow | survival |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | -20 | 10 | 4 |
| 2 | 90 | -50 | 10 | 3 |
| 3 | 50 | -10 | 80 | 2 |
| 4 | 120 | -10 | 70 | ... |
| 5 | 40 | -50 | 60 | ... |

Comment: Your example is confusing, why for `t=1` the outflows match `t=1`, then `t=2`, `t=3` and `t=4` ? Is it on purpose ? From your dataset I understood that the outflows is 20 so I would have substract 20 mulitple times. If this is on purpose, can you specify the logic ?

Comment: the purpose is to count how many period you would survive given the initial cash position counting the projected outflows  only so you need to sum the outflows in `t=2`, `t=3` etc and stop if the total cash + outflows is negative

Comment: Then I dont understand why for `t=3`, `survival = 3`. `50 - 10 - 10 - 50` is negative right ? so the result would be 2 and not 3.

Comment: sorry that was a type. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: @Nassir Bin. This is actually based on which cash value you are taking from as the initial value. For example, if we use `t=1`'s cash value, that is 100 as my initial value, I can have `survival=4`; On the other hand, if I take the `t=3`'s cash value, that is 50 as my initial value, I will have only `survival = 2`. Am I understanding this correctly? If you are not considering the inflow

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew exactly. This is rolling so i need to do it for every `t`

Comment: @gioarma thanks. Yes I will I want to check also the  performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```py
df['survival'] = [ (cash + df.iloc[i:].outflow.cumsum()>0).sum() for i,cash in enumerate(df.cash)]
```

Output:

```
   t  cash  outflow  survival
0  1   100      -20         4
1  2    90      -50         3
2  3    50      -10         2
3  4   120      -10         2
4  5    40      -50         0
```

**Explanation:** I make a loop on `cash` values keeping also track of the row number using `enumerate`. I use the row number to select only the portion of the dataframe from the current value of `cash` going down. On this portion of the dataframe I make a cumulative sum and then I add it to the cash. This yields a series which is negative when the cash is smaller than the sum of the previous outflows. I then set it `>0` so I have `True` values when it's positive and `False` when it's negative. I finally sum the whole series, each `True` counts as a `1`, so the output is the survival number you are looking for. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution. It's the fastest but also the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    't': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'cash': [100, 90, 50, 120, 40],
    'outflow': [-20, -50, -10, -10, -50]
})
```

I choose to use the pandas `apply()` function on this function with `x` being the evaluated row and `df` the complete DataFrame :

```py
def survival(x, df):
    cash = x['cash']
    i = 0
    while cash > 0:
        try:
            cash = cash + df.loc[x.name + i]['outflow']
            i += 1
        except KeyError:
            print('End of dataframe')
            i += 1
            cash = -1  # To make sure we leave the loop
    return i - 1
```

Then apply it to every row :

```
df['survival'] = df.apply(survival, args=(df,), axis=1)

# Output

   t  cash  outflow  survival
0  1   100      -20         4
1  2    90      -50         3
2  3    50      -10         2
3  4   120      -10         2
4  5    40      -50         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the test dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 50
cash = 50 # the initial cash

# I will not type your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'inflow': np.random.randint(1,10, N),
                   'outflow': np.random.randint(1, 20, N)})
```

Then the solution could be achieved with

```
# computes the cash for each period
ccash = (cash + (df['inflow'] - df['outflow']).cumsum())
survival = (ccash[::-1] >= 0).cumsum()[::-1]
```

Comment: thanks but it is rolling so I need to calculate it for every `t` not only for the first one

Comment: It doesn't make too much sense to me to compute survival after something died, but I updated to give that. My assumption is that in order to resurrect it will need to pay all the debt accumulated in the previous periods.

Comment: it's not computer survival after dying. It is to say: first step --> with the cash in `t=0` how many outflows can I survive? second step --> you go to `t=1` (accounting inflows and outflows) and check how many outflows (only outflows) you can survive etc